# No Such file or directory on go get github.com/mkilling/goejdb

Tags: go, ejdb

On running the command

```
go get github.com/mkilling/goejdb
# github.com/mkilling/goejdb
../../go/src/github.com/mkilling/goejdb/ejcoll.go:4:24: fatal error:     ejdb/ejdb.h: No such file or directory
// #include <ejdb/ejdb.h>
```

Is the error with the package or I need any other dependency to be installed for this command.
I am able to install Other packages with go get command

Answer (score 1):

You must [install egbd](https://github.com/mkilling/goejdb#prerequisites). The 'go get' command only installs prerequisites that are Go packages.

The [instructions for using apt-get are](https://github.com/Softmotions/ejdb#ejdb-binary-package-installation):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:adamansky/ejdb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ejdb ejdb-dbg
```

Comment: Whenever I try to install it with apt-get command I get 
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main amd64 Packages                                               
  404  Not Found
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net wily/main i386 Packages                                                
  404  Not Found
error.

Answer (score 1):

I found this in https://github.com/mkilling/goejdb, you sure got `ejdb` installed?

[image]

https://github.com/Softmotions/ejdb
[image]

Comment: Whenever I try to apt-get update after "add-apt-repository ppa:adamansky/ejdb" I get the error
Err ppa.launchpad.net wily/main amd64 Packages 404 Not Found Err ppa.launchpad.net wily/main i386 Packages 404 Not Found error

Comment: On trying to clone I get 
fatal: repository 'github.com/Softmotions/ejdb' does not exist
error